Filtering Dataframe for first letter of a Classification Code in a column entry that has multiple of them
I am trying to filter a Dataframe of patens into their classification codes. I want to only get the patents that have a specific first letter in the code, but each column entry has multiple of these codes, that sometimes end on different letter and also sometimes have different starting letters (They are IPC classes if it is relevant).
An entry looks like this for example:
"G09B 9/04(2013.01)|G09B 19/0053(2013.01)|G09B 19/167(2013.01)|G06F 3/14(2013.01)"
So if I want all Patents that have any first level classification with F, this entry will be given to me even though it only has F at the end of one of the codes.
I tried this, but i run into the problem
AIPC <- merge123[grepl("A",merge123$IPC),]

I am fairly new to R so forgive me, if this is a dumb question.

grepl("^A", ...)?

Thank you! With this, I am losing quite a lot of observations when compared to the number of A.... Patents given by the provider of the database.

Hi Cio, welcome to StackOverflow. It's a bit hard to provide advice on your question in its current format because we don't have enough information. I suggest editing your question following the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

In particular, focusing on including a minimal reproducible dataset and on outlining what the current output is vs what the intended output is. That will help people to help you.

Questions involving scanning strings for patterns are a bit hard without reproducible data, but if your data are in this consistent format - a capital letter, 2 numbers, the letter of interest, a space, more numbers -  you can just specify the pattern.

[A-Z] looks for any capital letter (could use [A-Za-z] for upper and Lowe case)
\\d{2} looks specifically for 2 numbers
F looks for "F"
\\s looks for whitespace
\\d+ looks for 1 or more numbers

So you could do:
grep("[A-Z]\\d{2}F\\s\\d+", x, value = TRUE)

Where x is your variable of interest. Here is some sample data to demonstrate:
x <- c("G09B 9/04(2013.01)|G09B 19/0053(2013.01)|G09B 19/167(2013.01)|G06F 3/14(2013.01)", #original
       "G09B 9/04(2013.01)|G09B 19/0053(2013.01)|G09B 19/167(2013.01)|G06B 3/14(2013.01)", # without F
       "G09B 9/04(2013.01)|G09F 19/0053(2013.01)|G09B 19/167(2013.01)|G06B 3/14(2013.01)", # F in different place
       "ABC DEF HIJ", #arbitrary 1
       "The cat jumped over the lazy fox", # arbitrary 2
       "123F F162") # arbitrary 3

grep("[A-Z]\\d{2}F\\s\\d+", x, value = TRUE)

# or (thanks to @Onyambu for commenting)
grep("(?<=^|\\|)[A-Z]\\d{2}F\\s\\d+", x, value = TRUE)


# [1] "G09B 9/04(2013.01)|G09B 19/0053(2013.01)|G09B 19/167(2013.01)|G06F 3/14(2013.01)"
# [2] "G09B 9/04(2013.01)|G09F 19/0053(2013.01)|G09B 19/167(2013.01)|G06B 3/14(2013.01)"

If this doesnt work, please edit your question to include data more consistent with your actual data.

here is another arbitrary: 123Z34F 2RT which will be matched yet I doubt should be matched. You could use anchors/boundaries/lookbehind

@Onyambu absolutely agree - there are infinite arbitrary strings that would meet this, but given the information in the question there is no evidence that there would arise (hence "...if your data are in this consistent format...") - word boundaries would add an extra safeguard - thank you!

Parhaps use (?<=^|\\|)[A-Z]\\d{2}F\\s\\d+
